# PrettyFaces: poor performance on every request

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, mojarra, prettyfaces

registering for new users in the pretty forum (https://www.ocpsoft.org/support/forum/prettyfaces-users/) currently does not seem to work, so i ask here for help:

we started to include latest prettyfaces 3.4.2 in our jsf 2.2 project and recognized a pretty poor performance on every POST and GET request.

we removed all our custom filters and servlet-listener so that nothing special remains in the config files, but prettyfaces stays unusable, although the rewrite-engine seems to work in general:

```
http://localhost:8080/vision9/member/576
```

after removing the pretty dependencies, everything goes back to "normal" state...

does anybody have a hint for this problem?

**Update:**

Performance is only fine when project-stage is Production. Setting following context-params as taken from 
https://www.ocpsoft.org/support/topic/huge-performance-drop-even-with-empty-config/
did not solve the performance issue:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.CONFIG_RELOADING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.BASE_PACKAGES</param-name>
  <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

here are our configuration files:

console-info during server-startup:

```
 INFORMATION: RewriteFilter starting up...    
 Rewrite 3.4.2.Final initialized.
 RewritePhaseListener starting up.
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.14</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>vision9</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>        
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>      
</context-param>
<context-param>     
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>   
</web-app>
```

pretty-config.xml:

```
 <pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                  http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">


<url-mapping id="members">
     <pattern value="/member/#{memberId}" />
    <view-id value="/member.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">

<application>   
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>de</default-locale>
    </locale-config>

    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>

    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.UnmappedResourceHandler</resource-handler>

</application>
```

Comment: Define poor performance... And what did you debug? Did you run it in a profiler?

Comment: poor performance = up to ~5seconds on every request. the time seems to be consumed in PrettyConfigReloader#reloadIfNecessary which is called on every request...

Comment: Try running in production mode by changing: `<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>      
</context-param>`

Comment: This was just a guess of mine and by inspecting https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/blob/master/config-prettyfaces/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/config/reload/PrettyConfigReloader.java you can see this yourself too. The source IS open of all these frameworks

Comment: fact, changing the project stage to "production" seems to put the thing right... -.-

Comment: Then for one reason or another, (re)loading the PrettyFaces config is slow or PrettyFaces trying to check if reloading is needed is slow. You can debug more if you want to know why... (I'm not a PrettyFaces user btw)

Comment: thanks for the hint. i will debug the sources and look if find a solution...

Comment: And read https://www.ocpsoft.org/support/topic/huge-performance-drop-even-with-empty-config/